# Convert database font from MS SQL to mysql utf8?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have old database at one windows dedicated server and now i buy a new linux dedicated server with php and mysql.

I plan to using php to pull out database from ms sql server row by row and put it to mysql database.

But problem is mysql using utf8_unicode_ic and i don't know which charset MS SQL server used.

THanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just running your code? Odds are it'll "Just work".

Caveats below:

You may run into issues in your data (although this is highly unlikely) because the character set you're referring to is actually a collation. That is, it defines the string "ABCDEFGH" to be equal to "abcdefgh". The "_ci" part of utf8_unicode_ci means it's case insensitive.

Some quick googling found that MySQL defaults to case and accent sensitive collation, that's good, because SQL Server does the same. You should check the collation of the SQL Server database, if it's "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" you should be good.

Comment: everyone should looking forward for UTF-8, don't we?

Comment: It's a sight better than ASCII, that's for sure.

Comment: "MySQL defaults to case and accent sensitive collation, that's good, because SQL Server does the same". This is wrong, MSSQL default collations are "xxx_CI_AS", i.e. case-insensitive (CI) and accent-sensitive (_AS)... if it is really default default because default is chosen during server installation and database creation

Comment: dude i think you are not fully understand my question. Let's make a example. I pull out a row from MS SQL server and put in to mysql but this not display correctly. That's why i think maybe need to convert like : iconv("what_to_put_here",'UTF-8',$row_from_ms_sql); before put into mySql

Comment: You're right, vgv8 I meant case insensitive and accent sensitive. 

tieungao, give me an example of a record you're pulling out that doesn't display correctly?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server stores character-based data in extended (i.e. depending on Windows, operating system, code-pages/encodings installed and used on server machine) ASCII for non-unicode (char, varchar, text, etc.) types and in unicode (nchar, nvarchar, ntext, etc.) types. I believe internet has plenty of material on this FAQ topic